# Django queryset based on input type

Tags: python, django, search, django-queryset

on Django 1.9, I have a form that allows the user to filter models based on their input:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        cvs = Clean.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if query:
            cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cvscore__gte=query)).distinct()
            cvs = cvs.order_by('cvscore')            
        return cvs
```

I want them to be able to search for a string also and have tried:

```
cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cvscore__gte=query) | Q(cv__icontains=query)).distinct()
```

The problem with this is if the input is a str, an error will be thrown:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Is there a way around this? Something like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        cvs = Clean.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if query **is an integer**:
            cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cvscore__gte=query)).distinct()
            cvs = cvs.order_by('cvscore')
        else:
            cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cv__icontains=query)).distinct()

        return cvs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside query everything is `string`. So, you should consider using `isdigit()`:
This method returns true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise. [More Info](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm)

```
query = self.request.GET.get('q','') # Note this .get('q','')
if query.isdigit(): # i.e '31231' as string, will be True
   cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cvscore__gte=int(query))).distinct()
   cvs = cvs.order_by('cvscore')
else:
   cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cv__icontains=query)).distinct()
```

Comment: This works, however refreshing the page should return cvs unfiltered. This causes a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: note this `self.request.GET.get('q','')` in my answer, the second parameter is the `default value` to avoid `None` value

Answer (score 1):

You can check for that when constructing the query:

```
expression = Q()
if query.isdigit():
    expression |= Q(cvscore__gte=query)
else:
    expression |= Q(cv__icontains=query)

cvs = cvs.filter(expression).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    cvs = Clean.objects.all()
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')

    cvs = cvs.filter(cv__icontains=query)

    try:
        cvs = cvs.filter(cvscore__gte=query).order_by('cvscore')
    except ValueError:
        # no additional filtering is done if 'query' cannot be coerced to a number
        pass

    cvs = cvs.distinct()
    return cvs
```

Comment: This causes a "Cannot use None as a query value". It works with this: query = self.request.GET.get('q', '') courtesy of Lemayzeur

Answer (score 1):

What About

```
def get_queryset(self):
    cvs = Clean.objects.all()
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    try:
        cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cvscore__gte=int(query))).distinct()
        cvs = cvs.order_by('cvscore')
    except ValueError:
        cvs = cvs.filter(Q(cv__icontains=query)).distinct()

    return cvs
```

Comment: This works when the following is changed: query = self.request.GET.get('q', '') courtesy of Lemayzeur. Thanks Messaoud